# complicated query in ms access 2013

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have two tables:

table1

1. > ```
   > emp   empname mangr   mangrname
   > 1       emp1   3          emp3
   > 2       emp2   3          emp3
   > 3       emp3   6          emp6
   > 4       emp4   5          emp5
   > 5       emp5   7          emp7
   > ```

table 2

1. > ```
   > emp   mngr    score
   > 1      3       18
   > 2      3       19
   > 3      6       15
   > 4      5       18
   > 5      7       15
   > 1      6       18
   > 2      6       16
   > 3      7       18
   > 4      3       19
   > ```

output will be

```
empname   mangrname   score_by_mangr    mangr_of_mangr   score_by_mangr_of_mangr    avg_score_by_others
```

I have been trying using the below query, but its going no where!!!

```
SELECT UD.emp, UD.empname, UD.mangrname,
(SELECT score FROM TABLE2 WHERE mngr =(SELECT DISTINCT mangr FROM TABLE1  WHERE mangrname=UD.mangrname) ),
 AVG(VAL(US.score))
FROM table2 US, table1 UD
WHERE US.EMP_ID=UD.EMP_ID
AND US.mangr=UD.mangr
GROUP BY UD.emp, UD.empname, UD.mangrname;
```

Comment: Would be great if you added a more verbose description of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Wat am tryin to do s to presnt scores in a tabular form.Now d score tbl contains employee id,score and manager id which means an emloyee s rated by his direct manager n also rated by manager of manager which s stored as 2 separate rows.He's also rated by oder people in oder rows. Hence score tbl wil hav say suppose 5 entries where 1=his manager, 1=manager of his manager and 3=other people. Now output table will have columns as empname(join from table1), manager name(join from table1), manager score, manager of manager(join from table1), score by manager of manager, avg of score by other 3 ppl.

Comment: I have been able to write query that gives desired output. I will post it after some final checking and testing. Sorry for the shortcuts in above comment. There was word limitation. :-)